# Counting items in itemize or enumerate environments

Tags: enumerate, itemize

Is there any way to obtain the number of items that appear in an enumeration? My intention is to have that number updated automatically when I add a new item anywhere in my list, so something like this would be ideal:

```
Here are the \numitems{mylist} points I wanted to address:
\begin{itemize}\label{mylist}
    \item important issue;
    \item another important issue;
    \item oh, and yet another critical thing.
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Since `itemize` does not use a counter really, `\label` (and it's at the wrong position anyway) is useless here. Do you really want to have an `itemize` or rather an `enumerate` list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`itemize` does not use a counter (with `\refstepcounter)`) -- The `\label` is useless then (and if it should be used, it must after the `last` item, not before the first one.

I've patched the `itemize` environment a little bit and added a new counter, that is reset and stepped each time `\item` is used.

Use `\getrefnumber{...}` from the `refcount` package to get an expandable number.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{refcount}


\newcommand{\numitems}[1]{\getrefnumber{#1}}
\newcounter{itemcntr}

\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{%
\setcounter{itemcntr}{0}%
\xapptocmd{\item}{\refstepcounter{itemcntr}}{}{}%
}

\begin{document}


Here are the \numitems{mylist} points I wanted to address:
\begin{itemize}
    \item important issue;
    \item another important issue;
    \item oh, and yet another critical thing. \label{mylist}
\end{itemize}


Here are the \numitems{otherlist} points I wanted to address:
\begin{itemize}
    \item important issue;
    \item another important issue;
    \item almost forgotten stuff;
    \item oh, and yet another critical thing. \label{otherlist}
\end{itemize}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following allows for an [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) interaction with a `countlist`, and perhaps an easier interface: You specify a `countlist` environment with a mandatory argument that would reference the list `\label`. An optional argument is also allows, which is passed to an `enumerate` environment in typical `enumitem` fashion.

[`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) provides the numeral display of a reference, although it's not really needed in this instance.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,refcount}

\newcounter{countlist}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{countlist}[2][]
  {\begin{enumerate}[#1]
     \setcounter{countlist}{0}%
     \def\countname{#2}%
     \let\olditem\item
     \renewcommand{\item}{\stepcounter{countlist}\olditem}}
  {  \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{\arabic{countlist}}%
     \label{\countname}%
   \end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\numitems}[1]{\getrefnumber{#1}}
% Alternatively...
%\newcommand{\numitems}[1]{\ref{#1}}

\begin{document}

Here are the \numitems{mylist} points I wanted to address:
\begin{countlist}{mylist}
  \item important issue;
  \item another important issue;
  \item oh, and yet another critical thing.
\end{countlist}

Here are the \numitems{otherlist} points I wanted to address:
\begin{countlist}[label={(\Alph*)}]{otherlist}
  \item important issue;
  \item[(b*)] another important issue;
  \item almost forgotten stuff;
  \item oh, and yet another critical thing.
\end{countlist}

\end{document}
```

If you want an `itemize`-like feel for the list, one could use a default `label={\textbullet}` optional argument for `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1):

Some creative use of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{itemcount}
\newenvironment{countitemize}[1]
 {\def\countitemizelabel{#1}%
  \setcounter{itemcount}{0}%
  \itemize[label=\stepcounter{itemcount}\textbullet]}
 {\addtocounter{itemcount}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{itemcount}\label{\countitemizelabel}%
  \enditemize}

\begin{document}

Here are the \ref{mylist} points I wanted to address:
\begin{countitemize}{mylist}
\item important issue;

\item another important issue;

\item oh, and yet another critical thing.
\end{countitemize}

Let's check the formatting
\begin{itemize}
\item important issue;

\item another important issue;

\item oh, and yet another critical thing.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to count *every* instance of `\item`, then you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{itemcount}
\newenvironment{countitemize}[1]
 {\def\countitemizelabel{#1}%
  \setcounter{itemcount}{0}%
  \preto\item{\stepcounter{itemcount}}
  \itemize}
 {\addtocounter{itemcount}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{itemcount}\label{\countitemizelabel}%
  \enditemize}

\begin{document}

Here are the \ref{mylist} points I wanted to address:
\begin{countitemize}{mylist}
\item important issue;

\item another important issue;

\item oh, and yet another critical thing.
\end{countitemize}

Let's check the formatting
\begin{itemize}
\item important issue;

\item another important issue;

\item oh, and yet another critical thing.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

However, the counting would go on in nested environments. It would be possible to solve the issue, in case you need it.

I provide for nested `countitemize` up to level 3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{itemcounti}
\newcounter{itemcountii}
\newcounter{itemcountiii}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifnestedcountitemize
\newenvironment{countitemize}[1]
 {\ifnestedcountitemize\else
    \preto\item{\stepcounter{itemcount\romannumeral\@listdepth}}%
    \nestedcountitemizetrue
  \fi
  \begin{itemize}%
  \def\countitemizelabel{#1}%
  \setcounter{itemcount\romannumeral\@listdepth}{0}}
 {\addtocounter{itemcount\romannumeral\@listdepth}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{itemcount\romannumeral\@listdepth}\label{\countitemizelabel}%
  \end{itemize}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here are the \ref{mylist} points I wanted to address:
\begin{countitemize}{mylist}
\item important issue;

\item another important issue;

\item oh, and yet another critical thing.
\begin{countitemize}{innerlist}
  \item With a nested list

  \item again
\end{countitemize}
\end{countitemize}

There is an inner list with \ref{innerlist} items.

\end{document}
```

[image]