# Automatically refer to first and last item of enumerate list

Tags: lists, enumerate, autoref

I want to refer to item list in text automatically (without using `\label` command).

Following is the code I am using. It could be any number of item and it should list starting and end list number without using `\label` command to each item.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

There are question list having question 1 to 5.

\begin{enumerate}

\item volute ped qui derferum nus sequi cus si invelicatur aboreste sin nihiten imusdae ium excepe vidus 

\item niam qui te si doloresti dolorit lam aut quatempori rectati atinis dolum rat plam dolori soluptatis assum reribus nienihi catemporitas des doluptatibus sequiaeri dolupta erferia dolupta dolorupta volupta speliquas as ventempos 

\item quate nis ma accus, sitatur assum et, sendant ant lit, cuptur sitem con nos sim rerum repuda et essi nos nusaperro tem reseditam, cullantibea doloremporro dolutem re et restion 

\item seditem eatia dolupidellit lab ius undit eum sit officiis eiciasp erorro int eium dolut fuga. Parunt, quas ex et asi de odicipitatia verro tenduciunt fuga. 

\item Et labo. Editibus que arcimpo reiusae rspero quat.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Sam, It is again using label to refer to last item. I was expecting a automatic kind of linkgae where \end{enumerate} is checked and last item is refered in tex. Is it possible!

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87412/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296098/35864

Comment: The duplicate uses `\label`, which OP explicitly wants to avoid.  But @execind: why do you not want to use `\label`?