# side-by-side itemize with overlay automatically

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, overlays

I want to have two itemizes, side-by-side, that appear along side each other and have the same alert as well.

So first slide is just the frame title, second slide is `item1` from both lists with alert colors, third slide is `item1` and `item2` from both lists with the `item2`-s with alert colors etc.

The picture is the last side currently, unfortunately, the entire right hand list appears with `item3` of the left hand list. I could do manual overlays, but can this be done automatically?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame{
    \frametitle{title}
    \begin{columns}

    \begin{column}{0.45\paperwidth}  %%<--- here
      \begin{itemize}[<+(1)-| alert@+(1)>]
        \item item1
        \item item2
        \item item3
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.45\paperwidth}  %%<--- here
      \begin{itemize}[<.(1)-| alert@.(1)>]
        \item item1
        \item item2
        \item item3
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

  \end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like the work of `scontents`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the easiest way (and also maybe not the best way) to do this:

(Solution for inserting counter into `itemize` taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296099/47927).)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcounter{itemcntr}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{%
 \setcounter{itemcntr}{0}%
 \xapptocmd{\item}{\stepcounter{itemcntr}}{}{}%
}
\newcounter{itemscount}
\newcommand{\setitemscount}{%
 \setcounter{itemscount}{\arabic{itemcntr}}%
 \addtocounter{itemscount}{-1}%
}

\begin{document}
\frame{
    \frametitle{title}
    \begin{columns}

    \begin{column}{0.45\paperwidth}  %%<--- here
      \begin{itemize}[<+(1)-| alert@+(1)>]
        \item item1
        \item item2
        \item item3
        \item item4 
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    
    \setitemscount

    \begin{column}{0.45\paperwidth}  %%<--- here
      \begin{itemize}[<+(-\theitemscount)-| alert@+(-\theitemscount)>]
        \item item1
        \item item2
        \item item3
        \item item4
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}

  \end{columns}
}
\end{document}
```

What does this code do?

First, I load the `xpatch` package, since I want to add a counter to every `itemize` environment, which does not come with such a counter per default. Using `\AtBeginEnvironment`, I set the previously defined counter `itemcntr` to 0 and then append to each `\item` inside the `itemize` environment a `\stepcounter` macro to increase this counter by 1. This means that the counter `itemcntr` contains the number of items of the last `itemize` environment.

Then, I define another counter `itemscount` and a new macro `\setitemscount` which essentially only sets the new counter to the value of the counter `itemcntr`.

Now, when you call `\setitemscount`, the counter `itemscount` is set to the number of items of the last `itemize` environment. You can then use the value of this counter (accessible via `\theitemscount`) in the argument for the following `itemize` environment to synchronize the alters with `[<+(-\theitemscount)-| alert@+(-\theitemscount)>]`. This means that the items in this environment are selected x times earlier than the current step, where x is the number of the items of the previous environment. This way, both lists are synchronous.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So itemize doesn't use a counter, but doesn't beamer use one for the overlays? Wouldn't it be possible to extract that info and use that instead of `\theitemscount`? Tbh, the whole thing with the new counters and stuff is a bit arcane for me so I only vaguely understand what is going on here :)

Comment: Yeah, this may be possible. But I don't really know how `beamer` sets those counters. To make it understandable, I will add some explanations to my code.